# Idempotents of a commutatitive ring in Lean proof assistant

Tags: proof, theorem-proving, lean

Hi I am trying to do some mathematics in the Lean proof assistant to see how it works.  I decided that it should be fun to play with idempotents of a commutative ring.  Here's what I tried:

```
variables (A : Type) (R : comm_ring A)
definition KR : Type := \Sigma x : A, x * x = x
```

I then get the error

```
failed to synthesize placeholder
A : Type,
x : A
⊢ has_mul A
```

So Lean seems to have forgotten that A is a ring?

So for example, if I change the definition to

```
definition KR (A : Type) (R : comm_ring A) :  Type := Σ x : A , x = x * x
```

then everything is fine.  But this means that I have to carry extra bookkeeping data.  Is there a way to use variables to get around the need to keep bookkeeping stuff around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Lean includes section variables and parameters only in definitions that actually use them. You can override this with the `include` and `omit` commands. But since `comm_ring` is a type class, you'll likely want to declare it as a class inference parameter anyway:

```
variables (A : Type) [comm_ring A]
```

Leaving out the parameter's name like this will include it in every definition by default, so with that your definition should work.

Comment: In Lean 3.3.1 and possibly earlier, the line after the one Sebastian Ullrich suggests should now probably be `definition KR : Prop := ...` (otherwise there are issues with a function from A to Type having type Type 1).